# Make 2d list from another 2d list with loops and if condition

Tags: python

Hello there i m very new in python and i think like c# and i cant do some things.
I have this list for ex.

```
    data = [["Bob","Algebra",5],["Bob","History",4],["Bob","Physics",7],["Bob","Astronomy",5],["Allen","Algebra",5],["Allen","History",4],["Allen","Physics",7],["Mary","Algebra",5],["Mary","History",3],["Mary","Physics",7],["Mary","Astronomy",8]
]
```

How i make this output from that:

```
MathsPerStudent = [["Bob","Algebra","History","Physics","Astronomy"]
                   ["Allen","Algebra","History","Physics"]
                   ["Mary","Algebra","History","Physics","Astronomy"]]
```

As i see i cant have

```
MathsPerStudents=[[]]
        for i in data:
           for j in MathsPerStudents:
               if data[i][0] == j[0]
               MathsPerStudents.append(j[0][i])
```

and with some way to fill the MathPerStudents correctly. As i can see data[i] cant compare with j[i] because the one is list the other is int from element. The point is in for loop how could i use (i) as index in a list like data list.

Comment: `data(i)` is incorrect, since that would be a function call. Besides, `i` (`item` would be a better name) is already `data[i]`: Python loops over elements of an iterator, not the indices (in contrast to e.g. Java/ECMAScript).

Comment: You should consider using a `dict` as an output. This lets you map a list of subjects to each name. e.g. in the end you have `MathsPerStudent["Allen"] = ["Algebra", "History", "Physics"]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `setdefault`

**Ex:**

```
data = [["Bob","Algebra",5],["Bob","History",4],["Bob","Physics",7],["Bob","Astronomy",5],["Allen","Algebra",5],["Allen","History",4],["Allen","Physics",7],["Mary","Algebra",5],["Mary","History",3],["Mary","Physics",7],["Mary","Astronomy",8]]
result = {}
for k, sub, _ in data:
    result.setdefault(k, []).append(sub)    #Set first element as key and append subject as value
print([[k] + v for k, v in result.items()])   #Form required list
```

**Output:**

```
[['Bob', 'Algebra', 'History', 'Physics', 'Astronomy'],
 ['Allen', 'Algebra', 'History', 'Physics'],
 ['Mary', 'Algebra', 'History', 'Physics', 'Astronomy']]
```

Comment: If i want to change line every name:maths how can i achive that?

Comment: the above prints all in one line, not as you have write in output with new line at end of last math

Comment: I used ‘pprint’

Answer (score 2):

You can do something like this (not a one-liner, but maybe easier to understand):

```
MathsPerStudent = {}
for name, subject, grade in data:
    if name not in MathsPerStudent:
        MathsPerStudent[name] = []
    MathsPerStudent[name].append(subject)
```

This gives you a dictionary:

```
>>> from pprint import pprint
>>> pprint(MathsPerStudent)
{'Allen': ['Algebra', 'History', 'Physics'],
 'Bob': ['Algebra', 'History', 'Physics', 'Astronomy'],
 'Mary': ['Algebra', 'History', 'Physics', 'Astronomy']}
```

If you want you can then convert it to list form, but probably the dictionary would be easier to work with for whatever you're trying to achieve:

```
MathsPerStudentList = [[name] + subjects for name, subjects in MathsPerStudent.items()]
```

Here the final list:

```
>>> pprint(MathsPerStudentList)                                                                                                                            
[['Bob', 'Algebra', 'History', 'Physics', 'Astronomy'],                                                                                                    
 ['Allen', 'Algebra', 'History', 'Physics'],                                                                                                               
 ['Mary', 'Algebra', 'History', 'Physics', 'Astronomy']]
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use `itertools.groupby` if your list of lists is ordered by names:

```
import itertools

data = [["Bob","Algebra",5],["Bob","History",4],["Bob","Physics",7],["Bob","Astronomy",5],["Allen","Algebra",5],["Allen","History",4],["Allen","Physics",7],["Mary","Algebra",5],["Mary","History",3],["Mary","Physics",7],["Mary","Astronomy",8]]

output = []
for student, classes in itertools.groupby(data, key=lambda x: x[0]):
    output.append([student] + [entry[1] for entry in classes])
print(output)
```

Comment: This is a nice example of  `itertools.gropby` can be used for. `lambda x: x[0]` can be also replaced with `operator.itemgetter(0)` after importing standard `operator` module.

Answer (score 0):

That's exactly what [`defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) can be used for:

```
from collections import defaultdict

subjects_by_name = defaultdict(list)  # if element is missing in the dict, it will be a list

for name, subject, _ in data:
    subjects_by_name[name].append(subject)

MathsPerStudents = [[name, *subjects] for name, subjects in subjects_by_name.items()]  # make a list of lists out of a dict
```

As you can see it is similar to @Rakesh's answer. As @pallgeuer pointed out, it would be easier to work with a dict instead of converting it to a list of lists. Get used to dicts in python as soon as you can!